# Flutter tflite(Teachable Machine) Embeded

Tags: flutter, mobile, tflite

[I am developing a mobile app and will bring tflite to embed in my mobile app. And then there is a problem like this How do I fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BBId.png)

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem?

The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\khong\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 36
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

tflite is an outdated version

Typically, you would have to use the newer package [tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter).

If you want to try, you could [try editing the SDK version](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/flutter-building-ui-with-machine-learning-capabilities-26b48bfa4887#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20%3Eandroid%20%3Eapp%20%3Ebuild.gradle%20file%2C%20add%20aaptOptions%20block%20and%20change%20minSdkVersion%20to%2019) but that is less recommended.